# Is there a way to improve the execution time of timezone conversion in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, date, timezone

I am currently working on a piece of code that requires formatting a large list of UTC dates to specific timezones in ISO format.

For a baseline I formatted them using only [`Date#toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString), and my average execution time on benchmarked tests was of **93 milliseconds**.

Here are a few others I have tested (with timezone manipulation)

---

#### Luxon

```js
DateTime.now().setZone(ZONE).toISO())
```

#### date-fns-tz

```js
formatInTimeZone(new Date(), ZONE, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
```

#### day.js

```js
dayjs.extend(utc);
dayjs.extend(timezone);

dayjs().tz(ZONE).format()
```

---

Average execution times:

| Library | Average execution time (ms) |
| --- | --- |
| Date.toIsoString() | 93 |
| luxon | 1367 |
| date-fns-tz | 1662 |
| day.js | 2137 |

With this, we can see that the timezone manipulation significantly impacts performance. Is there a reason this is inherently slow? And in any case, are there more performant alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you try to set the offset manually and then use toISOString.

for example, a function that convert date to PST timezone IsoString. (PST is -8 hours)

```
const get_PST_time = () => {
    const offset = currentDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000; // convert offset to milliseconds
    const pstTimestamp = currentDate.getTime() - offset - (3600000 * 8); // adjust for PST (-8 hours)
    const isoString = new Date(pstTimestamp).toISOString();
    return (isoString);
};
```

hope it helps a bit.